# Rails "can't write unknown attribute"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've been trying to solve this problem for the whole day, but I couldn't solve it.

I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Users::RegistrationsController#add_data
can't write unknown attribute `[:drivlicense_nr, :birth_nation]`
```

**user.rb:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  has_one :person
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[facebook twitter google_oauth2]


  #validate :password_complexity

  private

  def password_complexity
    if password.present? && !password.match(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)./)
        errors.add :password, 'must include at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, and one digit'
    end
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    # Either create a User record or update it based on the provider (Google) and the UID
    where(email: auth.email, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.token = auth.credentials.token
      user.expires = auth.credentials.expires
      user.expires_at = auth.credentials.expires_at
      user.refresh_token = auth.credentials.refresh_token
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.skip_confirmation!
      user.save!
    end
  end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
      super.tap do |user|
        if data = session['devise.facebook_data'] && session['devise.facebook_data']['extra']['raw_info']
            user.email = data['email'] if user.email.blank?
        end
        if data = session['devise.google_data'] && session['devise.google_data']['extra']['raw_info']
            user.email = data['email'] if user.email.blank?
        end
      end
    end
end
```

In **person.rb** I'm using custom primary_key since those are really important for my application.

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, optional: true
    has_many :cars
    self.primary_key = %i[drivlicense_nr birth_nation]

    VALID_FISCAL_CODE_REGEX = /\A^[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{3}[A-Z]$\z/
    validates :fiscal_code, presence: true, length: {is: 16}, format: { with: VALID_FISCAL_CODE_REGEX }
end
```

**People migration:**

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :people, primary_key: %i[drivlicense_nr birth_nation] do |t|
      t.integer     :usercode
      t.string      :email, null: false, default: ''
      t.string      :plate_nr, limit: 8, null: false, default: ''
      t.string      :drivlicense_nr, null: false, default: ''
      t.string      :fiscal_code, limit: 16
      t.string      :name
      t.string      :surname
      t.string      :phone_number
      t.date        :birth_date
      t.string      :birth_nation, limit: 2, null: false, default: 'IT'
      t.string      :birth_place
      t.string      :current_address
      t.string      :city
      t.string      :sex                       
      t.string      :region
      t.string      :zipcode, limit: 5
      t.string      :state, limit: 2
      t.timestamps  null: false
    end

    add_index :people, %i[drivlicense_nr birth_nation], name: 'index_people', unique: true
    add_index :people, :usercode,    name: 'index_people_on_usercode', unique: true
    add_index :people, :fiscal_code, unique: true
    # add_index :people, :pcode,                                                      unique: true
  end
end
```

**People migration:**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
      create_table :users do |t|
          t.integer     :usercode
          t.belongs_to  :person, index: true
          t.boolean     :admin, default: false
          t.string      :drivlicense_nr, null: false, default: ''
          t.string      :birth_nation, limit: 2, null: false, default: 'IT'
          t.string      :tpoliceman_id

          ## Database authenticatable
          t.string      :email
          t.string      :encrypted_password

          ## Recoverable
          t.string      :reset_password_token
          t.datetime    :reset_password_sent_at

          ## Rememberable
          t.datetime    :remember_created_at

          ## Trackable
          t.integer     :sign_in_count, null: false, default: 0
          t.datetime    :current_sign_in_at
          t.datetime    :last_sign_in_at
          t.string      :current_sign_in_ip
          t.string      :last_sign_in_ip

          ## Confirmable
          t.string      :confirmation_token
          t.datetime    :confirmed_at
          t.datetime    :confirmation_sent_at
          t.string      :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
          #t.datetime  :updated_at

          ## Omniauthable
          t.string      :provider
          t.string      :uid
          t.string      :refresh_token
          t.string      :token
          t.boolean     :expires
          t.integer     :expires_at

          ## Lockable
          t.integer     :failed_attempts,                      null: false, default: 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
          t.string      :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
          t.datetime    :locked_at

          t.timestamps  null: false
      end

      add_index :users, :usercode,             unique: true
      add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
      add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
      add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
      add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
      #add_index :users, %i[drivlicense_nr birth_nation], name: 'index_users_on_person'#, unique: true
      # validates :drivlicense_nr, uniqueness: { scope: :birth_nation }
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to do here is after i sign-up through google/facebook, the user must fill another form.
Now i need to also update the user to have the same value for drivlicense and birth_nation (my primary key). The error is triggered once the program do @person.save!
**Registrations_Controller#add_data:**

```
def add_data
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if request.get?
      @person = Person.new()
      render 'oauth_add_data'
    elsif request.put?
        @person = Person.new(person_params)
        @user.update(drivlicense_nr: @person['drivlicense_nr'], birth_nation: @person['birth_nation'])
        if @person.save!
          flash[:success] = "Sign up process successful"
          bypass_sign_in(@user)
          redirect_to root_url
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance for your help and patience!

**UPDATE**
**schema.rb:**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_02_29_181024) do

  create_table "car_associated_person", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "plate_nr", limit: 8
    t.string "drivlicense_nr"
    t.string "birth_nation", limit: 2
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "cars", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "plate_nr", limit: 8, default: "", null: false
    t.string "chassis_nr", default: "", null: false
    t.string "owner_drivlicense_nr", default: "", null: false
    t.string "owner_birth_nation", limit: 2
    t.date "enrollment_date", default: "2018-01-01", null: false
    t.string "enrollment_nr", default: "", null: false
    t.string "enrollment_nation", default: "", null: false
    t.string "brand", default: "", null: false
    t.string "model", default: "", null: false
    t.integer "infraction_nr", default: 0
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["chassis_nr"], name: "index_cars_on_chassis_nr", unique: true
    t.index ["owner_birth_nation"], name: "index_cars_on_owner_birth_nation", unique: true
    t.index ["owner_drivlicense_nr"], name: "index_cars_on_owner_drivlicense_nr", unique: true
    t.index ["plate_nr"], name: "index_cars_on_plate_nr", unique: true
  end

  create_table "fines", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "car_id"
    t.integer "fine_nr", default: 0
    t.string "plate_nr", limit: 8, default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "fine_datetime", default: "2018-01-01 00:00:00", null: false
    t.string "fine_address", default: "", null: false
    t.string "infraction_article", limit: 10, default: "", null: false
    t.string "infraction_informcode"
    t.string "infraction_motivation", default: "", null: false
    t.integer "deduction_points", default: 0
    t.float "fine_amount_reduced", default: 0.0
    t.float "procedures_amount", default: 0.0
    t.float "fine_total_amount", default: 0.0
    t.integer "days_nr_payment", limit: 1, default: 5
    t.string "paid", default: "0"
    t.string "optional_penalty", default: "None"
    t.string "tpoliceman_idnr_1"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["car_id"], name: "index_fines_on_car_id"
    t.index ["fine_nr"], name: "index_fines_on_fine_nr", unique: true
    t.index ["infraction_informcode"], name: "index_fines_on_infraction_informcode", unique: true
    t.index ["plate_nr"], name: "index_fines_on_plate_nr", unique: true
  end

  create_table "people", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "usercode"
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "plate_nr", limit: 8, default: "", null: false
    t.string "drivlicense_nr", default: ""
    t.string "fiscal_code", limit: 16
    t.string "name"
    t.string "surname"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.date "birth_date"
    t.string "birth_nation", limit: 2, default: "IT"
    t.string "birth_place"
    t.string "current_address"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "sex"
    t.string "region"
    t.string "zipcode", limit: 5
    t.string "state", limit: 2
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["fiscal_code"], name: "index_people_on_fiscal_code", unique: true
    t.index ["usercode"], name: "index_people_on_usercode", unique: true
  end

  create_table "users", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "usercode"
    t.integer "person_id"
    t.boolean "admin", default: false
    t.string "drivlicense_nr", default: "", null: false
    t.string "birth_nation", limit: 2, default: "IT", null: false
    t.string "tpoliceman_id"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "encrypted_password"
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.string "provider"
    t.string "uid"
    t.string "refresh_token"
    t.string "token"
    t.boolean "expires"
    t.integer "expires_at"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["confirmation_token"], name: "index_users_on_confirmation_token", unique: true
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["person_id"], name: "index_users_on_person_id"
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
    t.index ["unlock_token"], name: "index_users_on_unlock_token", unique: true
    t.index ["usercode"], name: "index_users_on_usercode", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: Changing the primary key in Rails should be your last option. Could you just make the composite key through rails & db validations and keep the usual rails id field as primary? You could even set up your routs to use your composite key as query params, if that is why you want it to be primary. Why must that composite key be the primary key in your app?

Comment: @robertoplancarte I wanted it to be the primary key, since it's what actually makes my records unique. The couple `drivlicense and birth_nation` is the key factor of my application. At least that's what has been taught me in university, i might remember wrongly, and maybe as you say i should revert everything to id field. The core idea is that i want to access the user and the person through this keys. Am i making some mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses the id field as a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) it then enforces uniqueness on that field in the application and database layers. This way you don't have to worry about creating composite primary keys (as in school).

Rails relies on a lot of [convention over configuration](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine/#convention-over-configuration), primary keys being just one of those things. You could configure any primary key you like, but Rails will fight you especially if you want to use a composite key. There is a [gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) to help you do it if you really need to, but I'd stay away from that  as it introduces complexity.

Comment: So basically for what I understood, you are highly discouraging me in changing the primary key and the only workaround is through this gem, right? It feels pretty bad tho that there's not an easy way to handle this. Especially I don't understand why I can't solve my problem by putting value inside my primary key and still getting the error :/. Now it's more of a curiosity, but most probably I think I'll choose to go for leaving the id field unique.

Comment: i took out all the primary keys, still i get the same error. I've no idea what is going on. From the form i'm passing the correct value but still i get `[:drivlicense_nr, :birth_nation]`. I have no idea

Comment: I think you will have to add a new migration to drop the column called  [:drivlicense_nr, :birth_nation] which rails creates when you use the primary_key option in the migration: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table

Comment: Solved thanks. I forgot also to take out the primary_key from the `person.rb`, i was so focused that it completely didn't cross my mind. You are a god